# Visualize un-distorted images received from the Leap motion cameras using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, distortion, leap-motion

I want to use OpenCV to visualize undistorted images, obtained after correction of raw images taken from Leap Motion cameras;

according to the documentation,

https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/cpp/devguide/Leap_Images.html

the following code should return corrected images: am I right?

```
unsigned char destination[320][120];

            //define needed variables outside the inner loop
            float calibrationX, calibrationY;
            float weightX, weightY;
            float dX, dX1, dX2, dX3, dX4;
            float dY, dY1, dY2, dY3, dY4;
            int x1, x2, y1, y2;
            int denormalizedX, denormalizedY;
            int i, j;

            const unsigned char* raw = image.data();
            const float* distortion_buffer = image.distortion();

            //Local variables for values needed in loop
            const int distortionWidth = image.distortionWidth();
            const int width = image.width();
            const int height = image.height();

            for (i = 0; i < destinationWidth; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < destinationHeight; j++) {
                    //Calculate the position in the calibration map (still with a fractional part)
                    calibrationX = 63 * i/destinationWidth;
                    calibrationY = 62 * (1 - j/destinationHeight); // The y origin is at the bottom
                    //Save the fractional part to use as the weight for interpolation
                    weightX = calibrationX - truncf(calibrationX);
                    weightY = calibrationY - truncf(calibrationY);

                    //Get the x,y coordinates of the closest calibration map points to the target pixel
                    x1 = calibrationX; //Note truncation to int
                    y1 = calibrationY;
                    x2 = x1 + 1;
                    y2 = y1 + 1;

                    //Look up the x and y values for the 4 calibration map points around the target
                    dX1 = distortion_buffer[x1 * 2 + y1 * distortionWidth];
                    dX2 = distortion_buffer[x2 * 2 + y1 * distortionWidth];
                    dX3 = distortion_buffer[x1 * 2 + y2 * distortionWidth];
                    dX4 = distortion_buffer[x2 * 2 + y2 * distortionWidth];
                    dY1 = distortion_buffer[x1 * 2 + y1 * distortionWidth + 1];
                    dY2 = distortion_buffer[x2 * 2 + y1 * distortionWidth + 1];
                    dY3 = distortion_buffer[x1 * 2 + y2 * distortionWidth + 1];
                    dY4 = distortion_buffer[x2 * 2 + y2 * distortionWidth + 1];

                    //Bilinear interpolation of the looked-up values:
                    // X value
                    dX = dX1 * (1 - weightX) * (1 - weightY) +
                        dX2 * weightX * (1 - weightY) +
                        dX3 * (1 - weightX) * weightY +
                        dX4 * weightX * weightY;

                    // Y value
                    dY = dY1 * (1 - weightX) * (1 - weightY) +
                        dY2 * weightX * (1 - weightY) +
                        dY3 * (1 - weightX) * weightY +
                        dY4 * weightX * weightY;

                    // Reject points outside the range [0..1]
                    if((dX >= 0) && (dX <= 1) && (dY >= 0) && (dY <= 1)) {
                        //Denormalize from [0..1] to [0..width] or [0..height]
                        denormalizedX = dX * width;
                        denormalizedY = dY * height;

                        //look up the brightness value for the target pixel
                        destination[i][j] = raw[denormalizedX + denormalizedY * width];
                    } else {
                        destination[i][j] = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now, I'm using OpenCV to visualize undistorted image:

```
            Mat imgCorrected(120,320,CV_8UC1);
            for(int i = 0; i < 120; i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < 320; j++)
                    imgCorrected.at<unsigned char>(i,j) = destination[i][j];
            imshow("ImgCorrected", imgCorrected);
```

And this is the result:

[Result](http://oi57.tinypic.com/33em0qb.jpg)

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are your width and height swapped when you copy the array? (It would also be more efficient if you put the values directly into your final Mat array rather than copy them at the end.)

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I'm sorry, I've swapped width and height. The result however in not so undistorted as I hoped.